# Why did Luke Collins choose The Portrait of Ruth?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-longest-ride

In *The Longest Ride* we have seen that Luke Collins chose to buy "The Portrait of Ruth" rather than buying the rest of the greatest paintings. So what exactly was his reason to buy that painting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first painting offered was the only one that wasn’t from a famous painter. It was from their orphan child, who painted a portrait of Ruth. It wasn’t particularly beautiful and wasn’t worth anything to the art world. In fact, no one bid on it, except for Luke. Luke didn’t see much value in the art by famous artists there, it was all too modern for his taste, but he saw great value in the painting of Ruth because he had spent time with Ira. You couldn’t spend time with Ira without learning to love Ruth after seeing her through his eyes. **Luke wanted the portrait of Ruth, not for its artistic or monetary value, but for its sentimental value.**